# Is it possible to do a stream http request with Django?

Tags: django, wsgi

We're working on software that needs to be able to upload 10+ gb files.

My fall back is simply chunking the data and making repeatitive POST requests to django, however I was wondering if Django and WSGI could handle "transfer-encoding: chunked" for a single http request?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the way the Django documentation states should suffice:

```
  with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in request.FILES['file'].chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

But if it doesn't, you can try [django-chunked-upload](https://github.com/juliomalegria/django-chunked-upload).

Answer (score 1):

Technically the WSGI specification doesn't allow chunked request content. There is however an unofficial extension that is supported by some WSGI servers to indicate that request content with an unspecified/mutable length is being supplied. This can be used to enable chunked request content to be handled, albeit that you may need to also configure the WSGI server to allow chunked requests as well.

The issue though is that am not sure that Django supports this unofficial extension.

What you should research is the unofficial `wsgi.input_terminated` extension for WSGI and whether any add on for Django supports it. Then work out whether the WSGI server you are using supports that extension. More up to date versions of mod_wsgi and uWSGI support it. I am not sure about gunicorn.